# Open Excel to Calculate and Close Excel Macro

Tags: excel

I have file excel contained macro (.xlsm file). This Macro is objected to calculate the workbook and close the excel application.

```
Sub calc()
   ActiveWorkbook.Calculate()
   ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
   Application.Quit
End Sub
```

I want to trigger calc() macro every time i open the excel. So in ThisWorkbooks, i add

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Call calc
End Sub
```

I stuck, when i open the .xlsm file, macro is calculate but the .xlsm won't close at all. Any suggestion?

Comment: Try ThisWorkbook instead of ActiveWorkbook

Comment: Hi Tarik,

Thanks for the answer. You are right, it must a ThisWorkbook.

And in additional, i have 3 additional Ad-Ins active that prevent the Application Close. after i remove the ad-ins, it working properly

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a syntax error in your code. You should also pay attention to the hint from @Tarik. The following code should do what you want

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call calc
End Sub

Sub calc()
    Calculate
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```